# prioritize group in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table named Products that is associated with another table named BaseProducts.
for getting the list of Products, I need to group the Products with BaseProductId.
but the problem is that I need to return only those products that has more quantity and the most cheapest. so I used Order. but it does not work.

```
    const e = await Product.findAll({
        order: [
            ["quantity", "DESC"],
            ["price", "ASC"],
            ["name", "ASC"]
        ],
        group: "baseProductId",
        limit:  100,
        offset: 0,
    });
```

here it's like it returns random items when using group. but I want to only include those Items that has first, more Quantity, second the most cheapest, and third sort alphabetically.

here is the sql generated by sequelize:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `nameEn`, `sku`, `barcode`, `quantity`, `price`, `finalPrice`, `sort`, `status`, `kianSync`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `deletedAt`, `baseProductId` FROM `Products` AS `Product` 
WHERE (`Product`.`deletedAt` IS NULL)
GROUP BY `baseProductId` 
ORDER BY `Product`.`quantity` DESC, `Product`.`price` ASC, `Product`.`name` ASC 
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

this is with group by:

```
[
        {
            "id": "3d2d181a-23f9-47b6-abee-ab61d1a86d02",
            "name": "rrrrrrrr",
            "nameEn": "nameEn",
            "sku": "sku",
            "barcode": "barcode",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 1000,
            "finalPrice": 1000,
            "sort": 1,
            "status": "status",
            "kianSync": 1,
            "createdAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "baseProductId": null
        }
    ]
```

this is without group by:

```
[
        {
            "id": "83939936-2c40-4921-9046-e40a1313bf77",
            "name": "rrrrrrrr",
            "nameEn": "nameEn",
            "sku": "sku",
            "barcode": "barcode",
            "quantity": 2,
            "price": 1000,
            "finalPrice": 1000,
            "sort": 2,
            "status": "status",
            "kianSync": 1,
            "createdAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "baseProductId": null
        },
        {
            "id": "8184b96c-1175-4de2-98c4-9faf231dabdc",
            "name": "rrrrrrrr",
            "nameEn": "nameEn",
            "sku": "sku",
            "barcode": "barcode",
            "quantity": 2,
            "price": 2000,
            "finalPrice": 2000,
            "sort": 3,
            "status": "status",
            "kianSync": 1,
            "createdAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "baseProductId": null
        },
        {
            "id": "3d2d181a-23f9-47b6-abee-ab61d1a86d02",
            "name": "rrrrrrrr",
            "nameEn": "nameEn",
            "sku": "sku",
            "barcode": "barcode",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 1000,
            "finalPrice": 1000,
            "sort": 1,
            "status": "status",
            "kianSync": 1,
            "createdAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-01-02T06:53:26.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "baseProductId": null
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You either group records by some fields and the same fields should be selected only OR you shouldn't group records at all (only order them by indicated fields)..

Comment: Please show the desired SQL query and the result so we can think how it could be converted to Sequelize

Comment: @Anatoly thanks for responding. here is the sql

Comment: Indicating all the fieds and grouping by `baseProductId` onlky should give you random records along those that have the same `baseProductId`. Is it what you want to get?

Comment: no, I want to get only the products that hast the most quantity with less price.

Comment: Ok, can you add several example records (some with different BaseProductId and some should have the same BaseProductId) and the desired result of the query from these records?

Comment: What does grouping by `baseProductId ` mean to you? I didn't see any records with different `baseProductId ` in the non-grouped records

Comment: @Anatoly well this is test data for now. in production I have 13000 products with 8000 base products.
I need to show 8000 products which is grouped by baseproducts, but only those with less price and more quantity

Comment: If you group products by `baseProductId` you won't get all records with ids that have the same `baseProductId ` - this is how `group by` should work - it's an aggregation function. If you'd want to get `baseProductId ` and max/min prices/amounts or a sum of `price*quantity` for certain `baseProductId ` then you'd need to indicate only `baseProductId ` and aggregation functions in `attributes`

Comment: @Anatoly I understand a little bit, but my knowledge in sql is a bit rusty. could you provide some code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250786/discussion-between-anatoly-and-sinamn75).